# Read data from PostgreSQL in spark return py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I am trying to read data from postgres in apache spark using python, but return an py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError

Here's my code:

```
import pyspark
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .appName("PySpark Read") \
    .config("spark.jars", "C:\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\jars\postgresql-42.2.12.jar") \
    .getOrCreate()

df = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5432/db_test") \
    .option("dbtable", "test") \
    .option("user", "postgres") \
    .option("password", "postgres") \
    .load()

df.printSchema()
```

And here's the error log:

```
WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform (file:/C:/spark/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/jars/spark-unsafe_2.11-2.4.5.jar) to method java.nio.Bits.unaligned()
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.spark.unsafe.Platform
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/spark/spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7/read-rdbms.py", line 17, in <module>
    .option("password", "postgres") \
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\readwriter.py", line 172, in load
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\java_gateway.py", line 1257, in __call__
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\sql\utils.py", line 63, in deco
  File "C:\spark\spark-2.4.5-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.7-src.zip\py4j\protocol.py", line 328, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o39.load.
: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:525)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.tryConnect(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:146)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:197)
        at org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:49)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection.<init>(PgConnection.java:211)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:459)
        at org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:261)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:63)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcUtils$$anonfun$createConnectionFactory$1.apply(JdbcUtils.scala:54)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRDD$.resolveTable(JDBCRDD.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JDBCRelation$.getSchema(JDBCRelation.scala:210)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.jdbc.JdbcRelationProvider.createRelation(JdbcRelationProvider.scala:35)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:318)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:223)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:211)
        at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:167)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:564)
        at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
        at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
        at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
        at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
        at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
        at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

By the way I am running my pyspark script locally on my machine, and I realize there's

> FATAL: password authentication failed for user "postgres"

But when I test to connect using Navicat and Dbeaver using same credential it succesfully connect without a problem? Is there something I miss?

Comment: You may need to downgrade your JDK to Java 8.

Comment: Thank you! @mazaneicha it works after I downgrade my JDK to 8u251

But I still wonder why it fails? it's just the latest JDK doesn't have support or it needs specific JDK version (can you provide me with a link or source)

Comment: My bad, I've just read 

"Spark runs on Java 8, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API, Spark 2.4.5 uses Scala 2.12. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.12.x)."

source: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on @mazaneicha answer it works after downgrading my JDK to 8u251 (my previous JDK was 14 or latest version).